# Gigya cdc sap account login lang is truncated

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, cdc, gigya, sap-cloud-identity-services

When login user via gigya screenset lang parameter is truncated from de-at to de and we have problems regarding consentments.

When user was registered correct language was set de-at by setting

```js
window.__gigyaConf = {toggles: {useFullLangCode: true}};
```

Is there any option to also used fulllangcode in login screen?